# Default date not being displayed correctly in jQuery datePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use jQuery datePicker to pick dates and use the following to set a text box with today's date as default.

```
<input type="date" name="startDate" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" id="datepicker" />
```

The default date seems to appear correctly but when I then open the date picker it goes to the wrong date as in the picture below. Can anyone explain how to get the two formats to match?

[image]

The script used for the date picker is:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks. This sort of works but now the default is the wrong way around ie. 10/1/2013 for 1st of October

Comment: which version of ie are you using?? ie 10 supports the 01/10/2013 format.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"})
                  .datepicker("setDate", $('#datepicker').val());
```

If is not worked you can stored default date format (mm/dd/yy) in input attribute.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"})
                  .datepicker("setDate", $('#datepicker').attr('dateDefaultFormat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: "Today:" + $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date())  
});
```

Thank You.